# Proper way to manage collection view cell layout on orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have few cells on my `UICollectionView` and on rotations the number of rows and columns changes. I am able to achieve this with:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isPortrait.boolValue{
        return CGSizeMake((collectionView.frame.size.width-2)/2, (collectionView.frame.size.height - 4)/3)
    }
    else{
        return CGSizeMake((collectionView.frame.size.width-4)/3, (collectionView.frame.size.height - 4)/3)
    }
}
```

All is well and fine until device is rotated. For rotation I have reloaded the collection view like this

```
override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    myCollectionView!.reloadData()
}
```

The end result looks like [this](http://gifmaker.cc/PlayGIFAnimation.php?folder=20160704174PTXoC89XDT2Sz1ZBFF4Mb&file=output_SRtlXJ.gif).(Sorry for bad gif)

The desired number of cells is achieved. But as you can see from the link, for a brief second there is a gap noticed when rotation occurs. This effect is not desired. Also it is bad to keep reloading the `UICollectionView` again and again just to fix the layout. I am able to achieve what I want but not in a proper way. Some expert ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution assuming you have a UICollectionViewFlowLayout:

First, add this to your ViewController:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ResultsCollectionViewController.orientationDidChange(_:)), name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

Don't forget to remove self when VC is closed:

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Then implement the selector method :

```
func orientationDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

Basically you just send a notification when the device orientation changes, then the selector invalidates your layout so that it gets refreshed.

**EDIT :**

Here is a basic UICollectionViewFlowLayout setup method :

```
func setupCollectionViewLayout(minimumInteritemSpacing minimumInteritemSpacing: CGFloat, minimumLineSpacing: CGFloat) {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = minimumInteritemSpacing
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = minimumLineSpacing
    collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout
}
```

Then in viewDidLoad you can call :

```
// Setup a layout
setupCollectionViewLayout(minimumInteritemSpacing: 0, minimumLineSpacing: 0)
```

If you wish to use a UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, you can use the following template, but keep in mind that you have to adapt it !

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

extension ResultsCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    switch UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom {
    case .Phone:
        return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100.0)
    case .Pad:
        return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width/2.0, height: 100.0)
    default:
        return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100.0)
    }


}
```

}

Comment: I do not have a UICollectionViewFlowLayout. I have just implemented `collectionViewLayout ` delegate method of UICollectionView. That notification is just the same thing as `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`. And collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
did not work for me. Could you maybe share how you maintained UICollectionViewFlowLayout in you code.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this collectionViewLayout does not changes the number of rows and columns depending on orientation. I think this provides a fixed CGSize for cells which is not what I am looking for.